# Can't drag Telerik MVC Grid column to group records

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, telerik-grid, telerik-mvc

I have a weird situation here, i have the following grid:

```
@(Html.Telerik().Grid(this.Model).
                    Name("grdEscolas").
                    Groupable().
                    Pageable().
                    Columns(c=>{
                        c.Bound(f => f.Nome).Title("Nome");
                        c.Bound(f => f.Endereco).Title("Endereço");
                        c.Bound(f => f.Localidade).Title("Localidade");
                        c.Bound(f => f.CEP).Title("Cep");
                        c.Bound(f => f.Telefone).Title("Fone");
}).DataBinding(binding=>binding.Ajax().OperationMode(GridOperationMode.Client)))
```

And as you can see, it's supposed to be groupable(it even shows the header with space to drag the columns), but when it's running, we cant drag ANY column to the header.
The funny thing is that if I do this:

```
Groupable(g=>g{
g.Groups().Add(c=>c.Nome);
})
```

The grid starts with the correct grouping, but I can't add any more groups(during execution) nor re-add the one I added by code.

What am I doing wrong? :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently creating the project from scratch solved the issue